# Xsl to dynamically remove parent element if child element name as parent

Tags: xml, xslt

Xslt to remove parent element  of child elements  in the below format.

```
<Response>  
<Info>
<Info>
 <Code>a</Code> 
   <Msg>fgh</Msg>
</Info>
   <Info>
     <Code>b</Code>
    <Msg>ggh</Msg>
   </Info>  
  </Info>  
   <Status>test</Status> 
    </Response>
```

Need the output like below format

```
<Response>  
<Info>
   <Code>a</Code>
    <Msg>fgh</Msg>  
</Info>  
<Info>
      <Code>b</Code>
     <Msg>ggh</Msg>   
</Info>
 </Response>
```

How to get above format using xsl

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following XSLT.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<Response>
    <Info>
        <Info>
            <Code>a</Code>
            <Msg>fgh</Msg>
        </Info>
        <Info>
            <Code>b</Code>
            <Msg>ggh</Msg>
        </Info>
    </Info>
    <Status>test</Status>
</Response>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Response/Info">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Status"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<Response>
  <Info>
    <Code>a</Code>
    <Msg>fgh</Msg>
  </Info>
  <Info>
    <Code>b</Code>
    <Msg>ggh</Msg>
  </Info>
</Response>
```